# can I use the same Minecraft account in my ps4 to my laptop ?? :)

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I bought Minecraft last time in my ps4 not the CD but the one on  playstation store so what I wanna ask u if it is possible that I can use the same Minecraft on my MacBook Pro?? :)

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, there is not a way for you to play on that same account. Sadly even the Bedrock edition (which allows cross-platform play) does not include support for the PS4, and is not available for Mac systems either. You'll have to purchase a new account for $26.95 and play the Java edition on your MacBook until the Bedrock engine is available on the MacOS.